# Why isn't my CSS file working in my header.php?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cdn

My CSS file isn't loading in my header.php. I'm using the CDN approach to get bootstrap.
I'm sure about my href path.
Thanks for helping.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Demo</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class ="top-bar">
  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my style.css file

```
.top-bar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #2c3e50;
}
```

[my files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8wrF.png)

Comment: Are you sure that you `style.css` is in stylessheets folder ? I think you are NOT refrencing in properly. Is `header.php` and  stylessheets folder are in same directory ?

Comment: start using the developer console in chrome or firefox, it will show if and where exactly your css file wasn't found. very useful tool.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try prepending `/` to the CSS path?

Like:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/style.css">`